# Help in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am new to writing test classes and need help in how to approach writing them .

```
 public static void MethodName(List<Opportunity> triggerNew ,     Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap){

    Id oldOppOwnerId;
    for (Opportunity opp : triggerNew) {
        oldOppOwnerId = oldMap != null ? oldMap.get(opp.Id).OwnerId : null;//oldMap.get(opp.Id).OwnerId;
        if (opp.OwnerId != oldOppOwnerId &&
            opp.RecordTypeId == AgentRecordType && 
            opp.StageName == 'Qualified' &&
            opp.Type == 'Agent' && 
            opp.Status__c == 'Deferred') {
            opp.AgentName__c = oldOppOwnerId;
        } 
    }
}
```

Trial :

```
private static testMethod void testMethod(){
User sysAdmin = //Creating user from Util class
    system.runAs(sysAdmin){ 
        createTestdata(//Calling this method to create a test opportunity with mandatory fields);

        Test.startTest();

       //** How to test rest of the logic ??**


        Test.stopTest();

        //verify result ??
        system.assertEquals();
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: What is your trigger code? That is what you should begin your testing.

Comment: @Eric - You meany trigger action ? i.e before update ?

Comment: No, the actual trigger that is calling you MethodName method

Comment: The trigger is calling the method by checking trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore. So how should I start off ?

Comment: With the trigger code testing. To help we would need to see it

Comment: else if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore){
        OpportunityHandler.beforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);    - Trigger code is simply this . Before update is a method in which we have the Method posted here. Opportunity Handler is the handler class.

Comment: Cool. Then start by updating the data for the various paths in your code and assert the results are as expected. Start by changing the owner. Assert results. Next method do not change owner. Assert results. Next method make values not match and change owns. Assert results. You get the point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43676/discussion-between-sfdcrookie-and-eric).

Comment: If what you're testing is a trigger, hopefully this reference is helpful: http://blog.mkorman.uk/testing-apex-triggers/

Answer (score 1):

To test the trigger you just need to create and update the data. As your `trigger` runs in `opportunity` so create a test record in `Opportunity` and simply update that. It will cover your trigger logic and Trigger call the class and cover that as well.

```
// Creates first opportunity
    Opportunity oppt = new Opportunity(Name ='New mAWS Deal',
                            AccountID = testAcct.ID,
                            StageName = 'Qualified',
                            Amount = 3000,
                            CloseDate = System.today(),
                            opp.Type = 'Agent', 
                            opp.Status__c = 'Deferred',
                            opp.RecordTypeId = AgentRecordType);

   insert oppt;
   oppt.ownerId = anotheruser.Id;
   update oppt;
```

And then use assert to validate the result then it populate the field with correct data.

```
System.assertEquals(userInfo.getuserId(), oppt.AgentName__c);
```

Comment: I have created a test opportunity . is that enough ?  I was wondering whether I need to do anything regarding  the method parameters -(List<Opportunity> triggerNew ,     Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap){

Comment: @SFDCRookie Just update the Opportunity record and check code coverage.

Comment: -1 for focusing on code coverage alone

Comment: @Eric check my updated answer.

Comment: @TusharSharma - Much better. Sorry, bit of a pet peeve of mine to focus only on coverage and not results. Coverage will come on its own and the test will be much more meaningful if one focus on results

Comment: @Eric Yes at that time I was busy so not able to put complete answer. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify the result i recommend to remember the Id and the OwnerId of the Opportunity you created in createTestDate(). I think the easiest way would be to move the createTestData() code into your test method.

Then before doing the assertion you need to get the created opportunity from the Database.

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT AgentName__c FROM Opportunity WHERE id = :opportunityId];
```

where opportunityId is the Id of the created Opportunity. When you got the opportunity from the database you can do an assertion on the AgentName__c.

```
System.assertEquals(oldOwnerId, opp.AgentName__c);
```

oldOwnerId is the remembered OwnerId from the test data creation.